# JW Player can not play m3u8 stream?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

with check this example, http://developer.longtailvideo.com/player/branches/adaptive/test/provider.html , I tried the example myself, There is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Provider tests</title>
    <style>
        body { padding: 50px; font: 13px/20px Arial; background: #EEE; }
        form { margin-top: 20px; }
        #player { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; background: #000; }
        ul { margin-top: 40px; padding: 0 0 0 20px; list-style-type: square; }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    Test M3U8
    <div id="player">You need Flash to play these tests</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("player").setup({
            file: '../m3u8/index.m3u8',
            flashplayer: 'player.swf',
            provider:'adaptiveProvider.swf',
            height: 360,
            width: 640
        });
        function loadStream(url) {
            jwplayer("player").load({file: url,provider: 'adaptiveProvider.swf'});
            jwplayer("player").play();
            return false;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            loadStream('http://localhost/m3u8/index.m3u8');
        });
    </script>
    <ul id="streamlist"></ul>
    <div id="panel"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the Jw Play can not work

BTW: my vlc can play `http://localhost/m3u8/index.m3u8`  well

Comment: This has been asked since but apparently it also got no quality answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988021/how-do-i-embed-this-m3u8-into-jw-player

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need to buy premium jwplayer license in order to play m3u8 streams. You can read about it in their site

http://www.jwplayer.com/pricing/

It says Apple HLS Streams under the third box, which is what m3u8 really is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's a missing !DOCTYPE declaration that you don't have.

I don't have ability to test this personally, but try this version that also includes other fixes based on the original file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Provider tests</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">

    </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js">
    </script>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
        body { padding: 50px; font: 13px/20px Arial; background: #EEE; }
        form { margin-top: 20px; }
        #player { -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #999; background: #000; }
        ul { margin-top: 40px; padding: 0 0 0 20px; list-style-type: square; }
/*]]>*/
</style>

</head>
<body>

Test M3U8

<div id="player">You need Flash to play these tests</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        jwplayer("player").setup({
            file: '../m3u8/index.m3u8',
            flashplayer: 'player.swf',
            provider:'adaptiveProvider.swf',
            height: 360,
            width: 640
        });
        function loadStream(url) {
            jwplayer("player").load({file: url,provider: 'adaptiveProvider.swf'});
            jwplayer("player").play();
            return false;
        }

//]]>
</script>

<ul id="streamlist"></ul>
<div id="panel"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
            loadStream('http://localhost/m3u8/index.m3u8');
        });
//]]>
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Note that you will have to be on the same Domain for this to work. Also, **jwPlayer** forum mentions that `.m3u8` works only for **iOS and Safari**. Reference [**HERE**](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/17350/m3u8-live-streaming).

To test a valid **.m3u8** streaming playback webpage provided by LongTail Video website with your device, access this [**WEBPAGE**](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/player/trunk/fl5/js/test/examples/m3u8.html). Caution when using desktop browser! It or **VLC Media Player Plugin** might crash with a sad face.