# Regex remove all string start with special character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string look like:

```
var str = https://sharengay.com/movie13.m3u8?pid=144.21.112.0&tcp=none
```

I want to remove at start `?pid=` to end. The result look like:

```
var str = https://sharengay.com/movie13.m3u8
```

I tried to:

```
str = str.replace(/^(?:?pid=)+/g, "");
```

But it show error like:

> Invalid regular expression: /^(?:?pid=)+/: Nothing to repeat

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14988021/how-do-i-embed-this-m3u8-into-jw-player there you should see your problem with jwplayer. If you have a problem with jwplayer edit your question or create a new and don't write it under every answer

Comment: I was found this before ask question. It's not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do this at the string level with regex, it's simply replacing `/\?pid=.*$/` with `""`:

```
str = str.replace(/\?pid=.*$/, "");
```

That matches `?pid=` and everything that follows it (`.*`) through the end of the string (`$`).

Live Example:

```js
var str = "https://sharengay.com/movie13.m3u8?pid=144.21.112.0&tcp=none";
str = str.replace(/\?pid=.*$/, "");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
var str = "https://sharengay.com/movie13.m3u8?pid=144.21.112.0&tcp=none"
var result = str.split("?pid=")[0];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use split(), which i think is simple and easy.

```js
var str = "https://sharengay.com/movie13.m3u8?pid=144.21.112.0&tcp=none";
str = str.split("?pid");
console.log(str[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may create a URL object and concatenate the `origin` and the `pathname`:

```js
var str = "https://sharengay.com/movie13.m3u8?pid=144.21.112.0&tcp=none";

var url = new URL(str);
console.log(url.origin + url.pathname);
```

Comment: I using jwplayer to play m3u8 file. I tried to add url like: "ne.hdonline.vn/d6a1dd9bcae0baa82aa51eab9ac95d43/s6/012018/01/…; into player, it not working, can you suggest any solution?

Comment: @vanloc -- Does the script run in IE?

Comment: No. It only for Chrome and Firefox latest version. I don't need it working in IE.
My code like: 
options.file = obj["file"].replace(/\?pi=.*$/, "");
jwplayer('my_video').setup(options);

Answer (score 1):

You have to escape the `?` and if you want to remove everything from that point you also need a `.+`:

```
 str = str.replace(/\?pid=.+$/, "")
```

Comment: Seem duplicate answer.

Comment: Quite coincidental, although there aren't many different ways to solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can use split function to get only url without query string.

Here is the example.

var str = 'https://sharengay.com/movie13.m3u8?pid=144.21.112.0&tcp=none';

var data = str.split("?");

alert(data[0]);